# Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, circuit-breaker

> Need help, While starting project i am getting error please see the error log i have attached
>
> Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hp.it.psoit</groupId>
    <artifactId>occ-api-ms</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>occ-api-ms</name>
    <version>v1</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <jackson-datatype-threetenbp.version>2.13.0-rc2</jackson-datatype-threetenbp.version>
        <commonlib.version>0.4.83</commonlib.version>
        <java-jwt.version>4.2.1</java-jwt.version>
        <jwks-rsa.version>0.22.0</jwks-rsa.version>
        <resilience4j.version>1.0.6.RELEASE</resilience4j.version>
        <collections4.version>4.4</collections4.version>
        <http-client-spi.version>2.20.25</http-client-spi.version>
        <aws-crt.version>0.21.8</aws-crt.version>
        <aws-crt-client.version>2.20.25</aws-crt-client.version>
        <sdk-core.version>2.20.25</sdk-core.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hp.os</groupId>
            <artifactId>commonlib</artifactId>
            <version>${commonlib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-datatype-threetenbp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${java-jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
            <version>${jwks-rsa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
            <version>${resilience4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>${collections4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-client-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${http-client-spi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk.crt</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-crt</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-crt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-crt-client</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-crt-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>${sdk-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> ## Application.Java

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;

```
@EnableWebFlux
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

> ======
> Error log

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:761) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:568) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:150) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at com.hp.it.psoit.ctrms.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:320) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findInjectionMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:276) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1082) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
... 43 common frames omitted

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181495/bean-creation-error-when-starting-spring-boot-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bean creation error when starting spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181495/bean-creation-error-when-starting-spring-boot-application)